# jQuery DataTables on Intranet site - getAttribute('class') returns null

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, datatables, styling

I am working on an intranet web application using dataTables 1.8.2.

The problem appears to occur only in IE9 when it loads the Browser Mode as IE9 Compat View / Document Mode IE7. This happens because by default, IE9 applies this setup to intranet / local sites. I have no idea why.

When using `fnSettings().aoData[0].nTr.getAttribute('class')`, null is returned. When Document Mode is set to IE8 standards or above, it returns the correct class.

Interestingly, if I try using `getAttribute('id')`, the correct ID is returned.

How can I get / set the class of a given row within aoData when IE9 is in this compatibility mode?

An example of my problem is at http://live.datatables.net/ijowob  (Use IE9's F12 Developer tools to set IE9 Compat / IE7 Standards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just IE7 bug. The most reliable way how to retrieve class name is to use `elementObj.className` DOM attribute. `getAttribute()` should be used only with unknown attributes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I actually was just about to update my question and say that I found this solution, but as you are 100% correct, you get the points :)